# Are there examples of scripthash transactions in the blockchain that do not use MultiSig destinations?

Tags: script

[BIP 16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki) uses an example of a one signature required transaction as a scripthash example:

```
scriptSig: [signature] {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}
scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 [20-byte-hash of {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG} ] OP_EQUAL
```

Has this been used in the blockchain?  Additionally, what's an easy way for me to grep through the blockchain looking from scriptSigs or scriptPubKeys that meet strange conditions?

Answer (score 2):

i could find these transactions:

```
output date         | input date          |  value        | output txn                                                                | input txn                                                                 | output script                                                             | input sig                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {pubkey, OP_CHECKSIG}
2013-01-06 01:05:04 | 2013-01-06 01:25:07 |    0.01000000 | 76db4ae9e12bcf95c0fe3f64ffbdba61b83e8099749a4ef721e69bce68eec8ae:00000001 | 4ba4f9ff28040e378a14422f3f19f341efac85b65f8cf778caab59ccdf9ef776:00000000 | HASH160,40 49 b9 10 32 94 06 bc 57 ec a8 6a 73 5c c0 35 71 f6 2d 28,EQUAL | 30 46 02 21 00 d8 ed 4b ef e2 ce 5b b1 fd 79 0a f0 6d b6 5c 88 26 9a f0 00 df a4 18 c8 fb ac 0d 99 4f 52 a3 a8 02 21 00 8e 8a a5 7b 1b 47 5d 17 34 fe 56 c6 67 9a e2 57 14 ee 5c 5f e9 50 92 6d 0c eb 9e 36 9d 88 66 93 01,  41 04 55 7b f6 c5 76 18 05 69 87 bd 55 bf be dd 00 21 16 d6 93 8f 37 50 cc d9 79 fc 8b f6 ea f2 52 ea 00 30 b0 6b 66 21 ef 54 46 73 0c 33 8c 23 d1 7c 7d 28 04 e1 e2 1c 63 36 fc 97 da 2a 78 b6 04 2d ac
2013-01-06 04:38:11 | 2013-01-07 04:14:20 |    0.00005000 | ad518a4a09472136cf5d3958a784721ae30b31eec00eba101963cee7fa10a5f6:00000112 | 5e5bdbb5c6bec825a8ac345cacf4be9bd61a8bb14483fc609d66fab8f5243ebf:00000013 | HASH160,40 49 b9 10 32 94 06 bc 57 ec a8 6a 73 5c c0 35 71 f6 2d 28,EQUAL | 30 45 02 21 00 c9 78 2f 84 48 ee c6 2f bf ac 24 b6 55 dc 17 ed a2 51 6c 06 84 36 67 78 3e 7e 7f ba 19 76 53 df 02 20 33 8f 8d bb 6f 3c 51 2d ee 54 d6 ca bb 48 07 ba c0 ea 39 3d e1 1f 6f 02 32 08 40 bf fc a4 9e 4b 01,     41 04 55 7b f6 c5 76 18 05 69 87 bd 55 bf be dd 00 21 16 d6 93 8f 37 50 cc d9 79 fc 8b f6 ea f2 52 ea 00 30 b0 6b 66 21 ef 54 46 73 0c 33 8c 23 d1 7c 7d 28 04 e1 e2 1c 63 36 fc 97 da 2a 78 b6 04 2d ac
2013-01-06 23:39:53 | 2013-01-07 04:14:20 |    0.00013298 | c44677b5309d4fd9eb15e79aba7a32740c92bc840e74e379bda03fd55175f626:000000da | 5e5bdbb5c6bec825a8ac345cacf4be9bd61a8bb14483fc609d66fab8f5243ebf:00000014 | HASH160,51 5a 01 9a 9f e8 43 d1 65 e6 69 d1 6b f2 92 7c 7e d4 a6 b9,EQUAL | 30 45 02 21 00 88 26 99 d0 cf 52 89 fe 34 1c 72 b0 4d 2d 87 38 b6 0c a0 a0 65 c5 40 9c 26 16 ec 70 cc 3b 5f bb 02 20 2c 03 e6 dc b4 db 41 13 27 0a 5f 09 20 dc 1e e9 7e 64 d1 54 b5 ee 4a 1a bb 2a 1c c1 09 98 40 5d 01,     41 04 d1 92 06 a2 d1 2a 69 a0 34 ba 1a d6 54 99 79 c9 5a b1 64 eb 96 74 a9 a3 78 16 39 e5 76 6d 9a 97 ac b4 cf 77 47 b3 75 e4 c3 c1 61 6f 37 5f db 02 ae d3 ec 5a 60 0f d2 61 9d 9b 11 d6 cd 92 6f 0a ac
2013-01-07 03:30:25 | 2013-01-29 02:13:27 |    0.09950000 | 91c8b08f305d895d6bc8f43bbdd36dcbc7f1d998e3df5e8f13dd9cdeebf15cb5:00000000 | 686212d2a49bda1f73c8cb1cf3f72e716b3a68ee12cfec5d1b3d86f1bae278d9:00000000 | HASH160,69 d9 83 14 fb c4 db ee 03 7f 86 f5 13 92 a1 4c 4c 1d 41 da,EQUAL | 30 45 02 20 69 bd ea 3b 70 ce fc 06 1d b5 46 b5 57 b2 d6 dc f6 27 13 f6 de 37 f4 a1 40 b8 83 70 99 14 a9 84 02 21 00 e6 10 00 79 53 9a a8 e0 ab a5 18 c6 ad 1a 34 be 33 69 ae 78 a3 5c 0b 23 40 cf e4 30 05 15 d1 ac 01,     41 04 3a ce db 50 e9 f1 95 4f eb 72 29 39 ec 01 0b 32 57 c2 8f 5f 35 25 ae b8 07 99 a3 2c a6 97 58 93 6b a5 d8 bf f2 a1 ab f0 7c fc 7e d4 49 8a a5 02 b3 47 00 de 93 0f 42 91 55 a4 6c 32 84 da fd 6d ac
2013-01-07 05:38:05 | 2013-01-21 03:22:57 |    0.00010000 | 3b2ca3e60a6d68dfcb6a87fee3898bd1f36b2da4a21b3302b0f0aa3d28a8931c:0000012d | 19adf8c075139a187fd46581767844af5701096f91ad3f9c876d5418ffbedda8:00000006 | HASH160,f0 6c 9c ff f4 60 d3 a1 f0 a8 52 cd 01 96 42 b3 3e 6c c2 1d,EQUAL | 30 44 02 20 42 1f dc 88 1a 4c a5 b8 47 2b 6e b5 35 dd 45 f5 a2 7c 6d e9 a8 ce 49 10 b9 73 a5 3e 06 2c 5b 30 02 20 60 eb 5d f2 a4 81 06 85 61 cb db 5a ef ca e4 18 0c f0 d4 ee 51 95 d0 06 27 1a ab 95 21 1f 11 18 01,        41 04 5f be f0 ab b8 96 88 fc 9f bd fe 65 a1 c2 4a 49 ce c1 f4 0c 4a 21 5b 7a ea 55 0c bc bd 71 8b d1 56 be e5 3b d4 6f 80 9c df 12 c1 b6 49 77 80 0a 2b 89 05 57 c6 9c 6a 9d 27 f1 b5 6b 5a ff bb 4e ac
2013-01-07 23:11:01 | 2013-01-21 03:22:57 |    0.00011562 | 82a64ce3ddc2e4ce11df80aa36f795ed2a86d7bc60de5759e779610e954e1f50:00000114 | 19adf8c075139a187fd46581767844af5701096f91ad3f9c876d5418ffbedda8:0000000b | HASH160,e3 9e 64 05 82 3c 9b e4 b4 94 41 cd 97 c9 3b b5 d7 7e 7b ae,EQUAL | 30 45 02 21 00 cd 9c d3 bc 1e b4 54 c0 9f 86 c1 3f f3 7f fa ce 4e 0a 0b 51 eb 98 96 52 58 81 8f 8c 24 14 bf 10 02 20 7d 54 c8 81 d2 2c 7d 1e d3 05 80 ec 24 f1 a1 0e 5b 79 6d 97 88 3a da 91 ea fd ef c4 08 60 6f 4d 01,     41 04 14 25 a5 c4 d0 67 f5 65 34 f5 90 ec 44 dc 10 73 2c ac 73 d7 0a 40 8f d8 4f 4b ee 21 0b e4 c9 25 23 cd 03 3a c1 94 05 1e 6f 11 9f 75 99 68 76 3d 7c 81 4b 38 66 0a d2 66 29 3d 75 a4 a3 c3 3a a0 ac
2013-01-08 05:06:22 | 2013-01-21 03:22:57 |    0.00005000 | cebad5da2661784e773b5f52d543cb691714c8a913ce4043cbfc71c579bd37ef:0000012a | 19adf8c075139a187fd46581767844af5701096f91ad3f9c876d5418ffbedda8:00000013 | HASH160,63 d1 5d 89 0b 6c 13 91 27 6e 23 da 76 e9 2e e3 17 af b6 8e,EQUAL | 30 45 02 20 47 b7 bb 45 aa e6 6e 43 10 a2 24 a4 e1 aa d8 3b 5b 6b 81 a9 77 3c 8b 4b f1 bb e1 10 b9 95 f3 0d 02 21 00 fd a3 11 6e d5 0c 06 95 6d 7f ba 31 f6 1d 45 02 aa 6b 9d c9 15 19 61 4c f8 43 67 22 d2 07 cb f8 01,     21 02 d5 38 69 58 78 c4 3b c3 8f a5 2e 59 55 5f ce 9f 60 bd 76 66 ca 88 e1 13 89 ac cb 5f 74 ec bd c9 ac
2013-01-10 11:01:46 | 2013-01-21 03:22:57 |    0.00005000 | cea225850ae919308a5dd96004cda20faf68a2dc1369fb86647ac53f64ad6284:000001a8 | 19adf8c075139a187fd46581767844af5701096f91ad3f9c876d5418ffbedda8:00000012 | HASH160,db 4e 45 49 5c 34 14 15 a9 1d f9 8d e1 f8 7c 98 ac 37 e5 11,EQUAL | 30 45 02 20 2c 85 61 04 c3 8f c1 8c 03 f9 f8 c1 5c ce a6 10 e1 16 40 bd df 6c 6d 14 31 c1 6c 7d 90 4b 68 e6 02 21 00 ed eb 3b f8 2b bb fe b7 82 16 f6 fe f8 70 ee 11 8f 99 6d 2d 88 22 e4 03 dc cc b8 4f 46 f1 86 98 01,     21 02 41 98 b8 4f 47 15 30 2b b4 43 a7 4b 96 51 49 86 64 ad 86 e7 f9 ae 68 40 c5 e4 19 e6 66 b5 f8 56 ac
2013-01-17 04:58:07 | 2013-01-21 03:22:57 |    0.00005000 | c0d8658c9c0d00168400edf95d553fa7f9cef31e30888040651c3fcf244a0f65:00000166 | 19adf8c075139a187fd46581767844af5701096f91ad3f9c876d5418ffbedda8:00000011 | HASH160,f5 fb 46 21 d6 e6 4f 16 d6 5f 3b 83 79 ba bd af 00 8f 51 98,EQUAL | 30 46 02 21 00 c0 6a 14 28 af 5b 93 4c ff 7d 45 61 c1 cd 64 99 96 34 3d ac 18 63 84 32 0a f3 72 11 e8 e9 3e 9a 02 21 00 f3 91 b0 ed c4 e1 ca 0b de 10 76 23 4a f8 3d a3 b9 a5 0b 11 56 e6 e2 93 87 f2 53 4b 7d 77 be f7 01,  21 03 ce a4 a1 27 c7 c2 63 80 5b ae 9b ec 8f 20 ff 24 65 db fb 89 30 9f 8a 92 1b 35 1d a9 ad dd 19 dd ac
2013-02-01 16:21:59 | 2013-02-12 01:41:59 |  100.00000000 | a511bea3b5dc09609c4853d817cde909fdcdc06cc9558500f155ca821d0d511b:00000001 | 59d48effdd0ef2767f1ad67e7340de3c285e3db2224f0a53b594fa52896a2868:00000000 | HASH160,f6 e9 a1 09 6d 7c 0f 3b 96 0a 66 18 e3 d1 bc c8 50 3a 1c a8,EQUAL | 30 46 02 21 00 de 46 53 ce 71 d3 71 75 e6 c9 6e 69 6b 77 1d 6a 44 cc da 79 48 2b a6 ee 4d 90 91 f4 5a 0c 2d 2b 02 21 00 d9 b9 a2 28 62 ad a7 2f 00 e0 ea a6 ea 2d 68 6f 86 26 df c7 6e a0 5e bb 8f 07 6b 58 e7 d5 db 1c 01,  21 03 05 c3 5b 0d 8b ec e4 9d 29 a7 00 c0 4c 7c d6 10 4b c0 14 c5 e2 69 26 67 8f 85 88 71 7f 29 52 da ac
2013-07-15 06:41:43 | 2013-07-15 06:55:48 |    0.10000000 | 0ac30703fc8004efeb3bd9d280268a5a94208476a382ec3e40cf9fc99858fe58:00000001 | 2e9bb33f48b0fe5809a8dcbd99b3ac003b1e26032adb299c6258b0ab8fbeac18:00000000 | HASH160,40 16 6b f4 72 7c 1d ff 7b db 79 48 33 12 a4 b5 31 90 cb 4b,EQUAL | 30 46 02 21 00 cc 18 80 d0 23 09 87 7c f7 04 db e7 f5 46 cb 56 36 6e d7 c5 05 a9 74 fb be 29 f2 ef ef cc f0 c1 02 21 00 b2 8a a1 db 0c 10 fa e2 9b c1 ba cf dc 33 75 69 70 3e bd e9 fc b7 c6 d5 d3 98 05 64 cf a6 a9 45 01,  21 02 be 82 2e 2d 82 0b 6b 7a c7 b5 cd 33 64 31 94 4b c5 45 16 45 49 4d 83 0f 92 6d f8 99 af bc 95 cb ac
2014-03-15 11:27:09 | 2014-03-15 11:27:09 |    0.00100000 | bff785da9f8169f49be92fa95e31f0890c385bfb1bd24d6b94d7900057c617ae:00000000 | 748f59fb05bd7cf488cdcdddb28ac5525b5be423e0fa14e77664200de0a5d019:00000000 | HASH160,03 f3 81 49 39 df e1 b2 0d ff c8 96 5d 54 79 50 a1 49 3a 8a,EQUAL | 30 44 02 20 67 ea af 83 84 16 d5 19 63 a4 64 33 d5 11 07 08 09 f0 31 14 6a 63 ad 05 1b 79 3e 81 84 29 4f 86 02 20 5d 74 19 33 40 95 24 dc bf bf 7f db 21 02 77 a9 b1 0d 0d 1e f1 9f 6d 04 82 71 00 ff d9 0d af 8f 01,        21 03 78 d4 30 27 4f 8c 5e c1 32 13 38 15 1e 9f 27 f4 c6 76 a0 08 bd f8 63 8d 07 c0 b6 be 9a b3 5c 71 ac
2014-03-15 11:27:09 | 2014-05-03 13:54:16 |    0.00050000 | 748f59fb05bd7cf488cdcdddb28ac5525b5be423e0fa14e77664200de0a5d019:00000000 | 773767ec5372f43c1bc1af3c0f4ddd2475580122127e536362fd622bd8ecf51d:00000001 | HASH160,03 f3 81 49 39 df e1 b2 0d ff c8 96 5d 54 79 50 a1 49 3a 8a,EQUAL | 30 45 02 21 00 b4 49 47 eb 50 8b 9e 86 4b 38 a9 af 0a 01 5d f7 ca 66 26 af 36 ce 65 7b 8c 9e 8e 4f 66 2d 8e ab 02 20 3e dd 5a 38 5f 1a 04 03 f1 d8 f3 3a 1d 36 d3 9b 3f 56 04 3c 05 3e 33 e6 a1 56 8e d6 6c b6 91 b1 01,     21 03 78 d4 30 27 4f 8c 5e c1 32 13 38 15 1e 9f 27 f4 c6 76 a0 08 bd f8 63 8d 07 c0 b6 be 9a b3 5c 71 ac
2014-03-15 16:39:50 | 2014-05-03 13:54:16 |    0.00500000 | dd0c261581a5f76fe52e0850b5c0d8df89afd9e84e5393fd93f01f21b17e41f5:00000000 | 773767ec5372f43c1bc1af3c0f4ddd2475580122127e536362fd622bd8ecf51d:00000002 | HASH160,03 f3 81 49 39 df e1 b2 0d ff c8 96 5d 54 79 50 a1 49 3a 8a,EQUAL | 30 45 02 21 00 85 98 97 78 b7 a9 02 20 c4 55 d0 1b 7d 6a 80 40 d3 fb ac bc 2d 76 25 60 d9 d4 03 d3 bf 0d e5 07 02 20 22 3e 77 2e d2 cf 66 64 f4 4f 48 51 ed fe 61 5e 7d ec a9 ca 5f 45 0d 3d 95 bd 69 cd fb c5 b6 93 01,     21 03 78 d4 30 27 4f 8c 5e c1 32 13 38 15 1e 9f 27 f4 c6 76 a0 08 bd f8 63 8d 07 c0 b6 be 9a b3 5c 71 ac
```

note: really long lines, scroll to the right for the `{[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}` scripts

Comment: Oooooh, cool! How did you find that data?

Comment: i wrote a tool which classifies scripts, and can show me all non standard ones. currently that is about 110000 transactions.

Answer (score 0):

http://webbtc.com/p2sh_scripts/pubkey
Sorry, this answer is very short, but I do not know what should I add